# Reset or override counter after page load

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I have the following span element on start up:

```
<span class="counter" text="Time will expire in %num% seconds" start="10"></span>
```

The *start* attribute is captured in jQuery and goes through a loop until it reaches 0 then displays the rest of the content.

I'm trying to introduce the option to either reset or clear the counter to my own predetermined time using Tampermonkey after the page has loaded.

So far this is what I have:

```
function init(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].getAttributeNode("start").value = "0";
}

window.onload = init;
```

Using alert I can tell the value is changed correctly, but the jQuery loop continues with the old value. I know that this would be a lot easier to use ID's and not custom attributes, but this is what I have to work with. Thanks!

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hXJdxs4g) entry of timer JS.

Comment: You have to change that attribute before jQuery fires.  `onload` won't cut it.  It would probably be easier to overwrite the timer JS.  What's that look like?  Link to the target page or a http://pastebin.com/ of the target page's code.

Comment: I can't make the target page public, but I've put the section of timer JS on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hXJdxs4g)

Comment: ***IF*** that code snippet is accurate, then `max` is in the global scope (possible, but not likely).  In that case your script could just use `unsafeWindow.max = {whatever}`.

Comment: Damn, worked like a charm. For my needs this will work great, thanks!

Comment: Well, that was lucky!  We got the bear, today.